# Capturing Feature Dragging and Dropping, ArcEngine 10 .net 4

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-engine, .net

I am currently trying to implement something that captures the feature that i clicked on and dragging.

Basically i want to be able to "OnMouseUp" figure out the item I was dragging, so I can do some calculations on that feature.

Does anyone have an idea on how to do that?

Thanks and Regards,
Kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to capture the feature moved using this event

Created the Engine Editor:

```
    if (EngineEditor.EditWorkspace != _scenario.GISMap.Workspace)
    {
        EngineEditor.StopEditing(true);
        EngineEditor.StartEditing(_GISMap.Workspace, _mapControl.Map);
    }
```

and added the following event:

```
((IEngineEditEvents_Event)EngineEditor).OnChangeFeature += new IEngineEditEvents_OnChangeFeatureEventHandler(EngineEditor_OnChangeFeature); ;
```